# operators in java: Can anyone explain to me output of the following java code

Tags: java

```
class {  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    boolean a=false,b=false,c=false,x=false;  
    x=(a=true) || (b=true) && (c=true);  
    System.out.println(a + "," + b + "," + c);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code? You can do it by selecting your question and pressing CTRL + K.

Comment: No. no one can...

Comment: When you do `a=true` you assign the value `true` to `a`. What is your doubt?

Answer (score 2):

The Output:

```
true,false,false
```

The secret of the output of your code lies in this line:

```
x = (a=true) || (b=true) && (c=true);
```

After evading the first trap - misreading the assignments (`=`) as comparisons (`==`) - one might think that each of the variables will be assigned the boolean value of `true`.

But fact is, that since the first part of the OR (`||`) - the assignment of `true` to `a` (`(a=true)`) - results in **`true`**, the excution of the logical expression (OR) is stopped, it will result in `true` anyway. 
So the second part (`(b=true) && (c=true)`) is not executed, hence `b` and `c` remain `false`.

Comment: The moral is: *never* type `if (a == true)` and then you won't accidentally type `if (a = true)`.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure, if it's an accident. It may be a test.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is happening is that when you assign `x` to `true` or `false` with the above expression, `a` is assigned to `true` and so the right hand side of the OR is ignored, as `x` is already `true` no matter what RHS is. Therefore `b` and `c` remain unaltered. It's in the Java doc's somewhere (about RHS of logical expressions being ignored) the same would apply to `x = false && whatever`

Comment: Oops, sorry.I takes me ages to type (I'm using a phone, so even slower)  Apologies for repetition.